# Copy constructor curly braces initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, uniform-initialization

> "we can initializate objects of a class for which we have not define
>   any constructor using:
>
> - memberwise initialization.
> - copy initialization.
> - default initialization.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     struct Work {
>       string author;
>       string name;
>       int year;
>     };
>
>     Work s9 { "Bethoven",
>               "Symphony No. 9 in D minor, Op. 125; Choral",
>               1824
>             };                    // memberwise initialization
>
>     Work currently_playing {s9};  // copy initialization
>     Work none {};                 // default initialization
> ```

The C++ Programming Language 4th Ed. Chapter 17.3.1

For example:

```
   struct Data
     {
        int mMember1;
        float mMember2;
        char mMember3;
     };

     int main()
     {
         Data aData_1{1,0.3,33};
         Data aData_2{aData_1};

         return EXIT_SUCCESS;
     }
```

This must work, althought I get a compiler error as much with GCC as with Clang. The error is "cannot convert Data to int" in both compilers. However, implementing the copy constructor this error disappear or without implenting it but using the round braces syntax. The problem is a little stupid and changing the curly for the round braces the problem get solved. But why the rules of TC++PL are not followed?, is a compilator issue or I'm misunderstanding something?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is fixed by a DR to C++14, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776359/explicit-copy-constructor-and-uniform-initialization/31776937)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the behaviour conforms with 8.5.4 (List initialization), sentence 3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> — If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
>
> [...]
>
> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` [...] the object or reference is initialized from that element;

You were expecting the second item in my abbreviated quote to apply, but the first item takes precedence: Since `Data` is indeed an aggregate, the one-element-list clause is never considered.

---

Your quote from the book appears to be a [known error](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html). The language is allegedly going to be fixed to match the book in C++14.

Comment: I have edit the message from your answer and I have include the code in the book. In this code seems to be applied the second behaviour.

Comment: @JoseLuis The book is simply incorrect. It may have been the intent of the authors of the brace-initialization proposal that this work but if so then they did not successfully specify this.

Comment: @JoseLuis: See the [errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html), allegedly fixed in C++14.