# Too many elements in struct initializer

Tags: c++

Why does this code give an error instead of calling the move-constructor?

```
struct A
{
};

int main()
{
    A a{A()}; // error: too many initializers for 'A'
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce822fcbda0f7db9

Can I not call a constructor on an aggregate with uniform-initialization?

Comment: That's a defect in the Standard: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467

Comment: @dyp How'd you find that so fast? lol

Comment: Because I knew already about that defect :) I just had to find the number, and for that, I just searched the defect report page for the new text of a recent draft "If T is a class type and the initializer list". The defects typically contain proposed resolutions.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21340801 Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19347004 I searched for "aggregate copy uniform site:stackoverflow.com"